# Querying with Many To Many in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

so I have two tables: "Group" and "Users" which have a many to many relationship. A group can have many users, and a user can have many groups. I need to be able to query all groups the user is in, and I also need to be able to have all of the other users that are in the group. Right now I am only able to query all the user's groups but in the group.users property it gives me back only one user.

Comment: You're not storing the list of users in a group as a comma-separated string, are you? I think you should show an example of your tables (use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and a few rows of sample data. It would be best if you create a working example at one of the online SQL fiddle sites (one example is https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a left outer join from group to users and then doing another from users to group and union all to get all permutations or union to get distinct permutations.

Pseudo Code.

```
Select USERID, GroupID
FROM User
LEFT OUTER JOIN Group
ON Group.UserID = User.UserID

UNION  --- Or UNION ALL If you wanted all relationships without removal of duplicates.   

SELECT UserID, GroupID
FROM Group
LEFT OUTER JOIN User
ON User.GroupID = Group.GroupID
```